# PowerShell output to file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0

I want to save the results from my PowerShell script to a text file. How can I do that?

```
GET-CHILDITEM  -recurse C:\Enlistment\DAX\* | SELECT-STRING -pattern "BatchIL.start()"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quite easily:  :-)

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Enlistment\DAX -r | Select-String "BatchIL.start()" > results.txt
```

If you don't like the default Unicode encoding of results.txt you can also do it this way:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Enlistment\DAX -r | Select-String "BatchIL.start()" | 
    Out-File results.txt -Encoding Ascii
```

Comment: Where the file will be save?

Comment: `results.txt` is a relative path = it will be saved in the folder your powershell session is in. If you don't know what location that will be, use an aboslute path (e.g. `c:\results.txt`)

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to use the "Add-Content" commandlet:

```
add-content <fileLocation> (CHILDITEM  -recurse C:\Enlistment\DAX\* | SELECT-STRING -pattern "BatchIL.start()")
```

You can also use `Join-Path` in brackets `()` in the file location for something like this:

```
add-content (Join-Path $env:UserProfile "OutputFile.txt") (CHILDITEM  -recurse C:\Enlistment\DAX\* | SELECT-STRING -pattern "BatchIL.start()")
```

That would make it a bit more portable if you need to run it on other machines and want to avoid hard coding.  The above example will put the whole output of you command into "OutputFile.txt" into the root of the User's profile (for example `C:\Users\Username` in Windows Vista & 7)